# Subscription makes impact on access control in Mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have single line in Mosquitto ACL file:

```
pattern read write s2
```

I'm trying to post to `s2` :

```
mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.8 -t s2 --cafile ca.crt -m "test" -p 8883 -d -u b -P b -i b
```

Got results in Mosquitto and client consoles below.

Mosquitto:

```
1577876055: New connection from 192.168.1.222 on port 8883.
1577876055: New client connected from 192.168.1.222 as b (c1, k60, ub).
1577876055: Sending CONNACK to b (0)
1577876055: Denied PUBLISH from b (d0, q0, r0, m0, 's2', ... (4 bytes))
1577876055: Received DISCONNECT from b
```

Client:

```
Client b sending CONNECT
Client b received CONNACK
Client b sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m1, 's2', ... (4 bytes))
Client b sending DISCONNECT
```

Then I did subscription to `s2` :

```
mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.8 -t s2 --cafile ca.crt -p 8883 -d -u b -P b
```

And tried again the same publishing:

```
mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.8 -t s2 --cafile ca.crt -m "test" -p 8883 -d -u b -P b -i b
```

Now Mosquitto rejects my publishing:

Mosquitto:

```
1577876215: New connection from 192.168.1.222 on port 8883.
1577876215: New client connected from 192.168.1.222 as b (c1, k60, ub).
1577876215: Sending CONNACK to b (0)
1577876215: Denied PUBLISH from b (d0, q0, r0, m0, 's2', ... (4 bytes))
1577876215: Received DISCONNECT from b
```

Client:

```
Client b sending CONNECT
Client b received CONNACK
Client b sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m1, 's2', ... (4 bytes))
Client b sending DISCONNECT
```

Now Mosquitto reports Denied PUBLISH. Why it denieds publishing only when there are active subscribers?

What is wrong with ACL record? Why I can't publish and subscribe at all?

Comment: Edit the question to show the whole ACL file. If it just contains that one line then that rule will only be used for anonymous users. Also `pattern` expects substitution wildcards.

Comment: Also there should be no space between `read` and `write`

Comment: In case I omit space between `read write` I will get error in Mosquitto server ` Empty invalid topic access type in acl_file.`

Comment: That's because your `pattern` doesn't contain a `%u` or `%c` (it should be a `topic` entry)